# After becoming a werewolf in skyrim, I can't use anything. Why?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I become a werewolf with the companions, I go to do the gallows mission to kill werewolf hunters (after turning back into a human and I need to be able to open a door to do the mission), but I can't use anything. Can't pick plants, loot bodies or chests, or open doors. Have to reload last few saves to be able to use it again. Any way to fix it so I can complete the mission?
I'm on ps4 btw

Comment: This might be a bug where the game still thinks you are a werewolf even though you are in human form

Comment: Have you tried continuing from one of the saves where you don't have this problem?

Comment: To clarify: when you cant pick up anything, you are in human form, right?

Comment: SPYBUG96 yeah, when I turn back and start the next mission and realise the bug I immediately go back to an earlier save to try again, but it still doesn't let me continue

Comment: AK_is_curious yeah, I'm in human form

Comment: Have you tried going Wolf and then going back again?  There may be a flag failing to clear regarding your controls.  If you have it, the Ring of Hircine can help speed this along.

Comment: @CDove Please put this into an answer box, instead of answering in the comments. Many people frown upon that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better answer and I actually solved the problem for myself. I just encountered this issue as well, plus the beast form ability wasn't showing up in my powers menu.

For me it was a mod issue. The culprit ended up being "Summon were beast (xbox1) by ImperialAgent1992. Once I disabled that mod werewolf form began acting normally even after I transformed into a human and I was able to pull off the vampire lord/werewolf hybrid glitch (which I wasn't able to do when my action button was disabled. In order to diagnose this problem, what I did was deactivate every mod that had anything to do with werewolves whether it affected my character or not. Then see if the glitch still occurs and if it doesn't then reactivate each mod one by one until the glitch occurs again. Then delete that mod. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is assuming that the OP was even using mods at the time. So might not even be the cause

Comment: Yes you are right. If someone has had this glitch on unmodded skyrim let's read it. If it is a mod issue then this is the best advice I can give and it worked for me. Other than deleting all mods and reinstalling the game there's not much more I can say. Other than the fact I've encountered most of the mod issues that exist, and if I haven't I will. I hope that helps the OP. I was looking at deleting all mods and reinstalling skyrim by this point anyway.

Comment: I'm on xbox one btw but pretty savvy with console commands on pc and troubleshooting I've done a lot when it affects me.